# C++ quicksort with 2 requirements

Tags: c++

My goal is to sort a list of words according to two criteria:

- the primary criterion is increasing word length,
- the secondary criterion is alphabetical order

For example:

```
{red,a,three,b,four,aeoli}
```

should be sorted as:

```
{a,b,red,four,aeoli,three}.
```

I have two separate quicksorts:  one on length followed by one on alphabetical.

I was just curious how to merge these two?
The main problem I am encountering is I don't know how to sort alphabetically while taking the length into mind, and running through the whole list.

Any advice is appreciated, the following code is my main and the quicksort functions:

```
Vector<String> words;
    String word;
    ifstream inFile;
    inFile.open("practice.txt");
    while(!inFile.eof()){
        getLine(inFile,word);
        words.push_back(word);
    }
    inFile.close();
    String pivot = "qog";
    if(words[2] < pivot)
        cout << "Bigger" << endl;
    words.quicksort(2,words.length()-2);
    words.quicksort2(2,words.length()-2);
```

the quicksort for length

```
template <typename T>
void Vector<T>::quicksort(int left, int right)
{
    int i = left;
    int j = right;
    String pivot = data[(left+right)/2];

    if(i <= j)
    {
        while(data[i].getLength() < pivot.getLength())
        i++;
        while(pivot.getLength() < data[j].getLength())
        j--;

    }

    if(i <= j)
    {
        String temp = data[i];
        data[i] = data[j];
        data[j] = temp;
        i++;
        j--;
    }

    if(left < j)
        quicksort(left,j);
    if(i < right)
        quicksort(i,right);

}
```

and the one for letters

```
template <typename T>
void Vector<T>::quicksort2(int left, int right)
{
    int i = left;
    int j = right;
    String pivot = data[(left+right)/2];

    if(i <= j)
    {
        while(data[i] < pivot)
        i++;
        while(pivot < data[j])
        j--;

    }

    if(i <= j)
    {
        String temp = data[i];
        data[i] = data[j];
        data[j] = temp;
        i++;
        j--;
    }

    if(left < j)
        quicksort2(left,j);
    if(i < right)
        quicksort2(i,right);


}
```

NOTE: This is done with my own custom Vector and String classes, both versions run perfectly, so my main problem is the logic of the sort itself -- how to get them to run together.

Also I can only use iostream, fstream and cstring, along with anything else I implement myself.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: To sort by one thing and also by another, either use `std::stable_sort` or `std::sort` with `std::tie`.

Comment: Normally [sorting functions take a comparison function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) as a parameter. You can pass `[](const std::string &lhs, const std::string &rhs) { if (lhs.size() != rhs.size()) { return lhs.size() < rhs.size(); } return lhs < rhs;}` as the comparison function which should implement your logic.

Comment: I can only use iostring,fstring and cstring headers (Justin)

Comment: @Justin sorry about that, but yeah have those requirements

Comment: I just read the NOTE.  My sympathies go out to you. Why do instructors do this? @#$%^&!!

Comment: cstring?  How C can you be?

Comment: I am through editing my answer. If you have any questions, fire away. I'll be here for a while.

Comment: @JiveDadson I would really appreciate your help, I have managed to sort it correctly, but the professor wants it as optimized and as fast as possible is there any way I can show you the code, and get your ideas on tweaks, since I have never had to worry about the speed of a program, and as of now it works but is pretty slow

Answer (score 1):

Just work backwards from a sensible implementation using `std`, re-implementing (cut down) versions of the things you use.

```
sort(vec.begin(), vec.end(), [](auto & lhs, auto & rhs){ return tie(lhs.size(), lhs) < tie(rhs.size(), rhs); });
```

We then need implementations of `tuple`, `sort` and `tie`

```
struct tuple
{
    const int & first;
    const String & second;
};

bool operator<(const tuple & lhs, const tuple & rhs)
{
    if (lhs.first < rhs.first) return true;
    if (rhs.first < lhs.first) return false;
    return lhs.second < rhs.second;
}

tuple tie(const int & first, const String & second)
{
    return { first, second };
}
```

We can then adapt your implementation of `Vector::quicksort`

```
template <typename Iter, typename Comp>
void quicksort(Iter left, Iter right, Comp comp)
{
    auto distance = (right - left) / 2
    Iter l = left;
    Iter pivot = left + distance;
    Iter r = right;

    if(l <= r)
    {
        for(;comp(*l, *pivot); ++l);
        for(;comp(*pivot, *r); --j);
    }

    if(i <= j)
    {
        String temp = *i;
        *i = *j;
        *j = temp;
        ++i;
        --j;
    }

    if(left < j)
        quicksort(left, j, comp);
    if(i < right)
        quicksort(i, right, comp);
}
```

Or we can instead look at [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24650627/2610810), and also implement `partition`, `find_if_not`, etc

> ```
> template<class FwdIt, class Compare = std::less<>>
> void quick_sort(FwdIt first, FwdIt last, Compare cmp = Compare{})
> {
>     auto const N = distance(first, last);
>     if (N <= 1) return;
>     auto const pivot = *next(first, N / 2);
>     auto const middle1 = partition(first, last, [=](auto const& elem){ 
>         return cmp(elem, pivot); 
>     });
>     auto const middle2 = partition(middle1, last, [=](auto const& elem){ 
>         return !cmp(pivot, elem);
>     });
>     quick_sort(first, middle1, cmp); // assert(std::is_sorted(first, middle1, cmp));
>     quick_sort(middle2, last, cmp);  // assert(std::is_sorted(middle2, last, cmp));
> }
>
> template<class ForwardIt, class UnaryPredicate>
> ForwardIt partition(ForwardIt first, ForwardIt last, UnaryPredicate p)
> {
>     first = find_if_not(first, last, p);
>     if (first == last) return first;
>
>     for (ForwardIt i = next(first); i != last; ++i) {
>         if (p(*i)) {
>             iter_swap(i, first);
>             ++first;
>         }
>     }
>     return first;
> }
>
> template<class InputIt, class UnaryPredicate>
> constexpr InputIt find_if_not(InputIt first, InputIt last, UnaryPredicate q)
> {
>     for (; first != last; ++first) {
>         if (!q(*first)) {
>             return first;
>         }
>     }
>     return last;
> }
>
> template<class InputIt>
> void iter_swap(InputIt a, InputIt b)
> {
>     using value_type = typename InputIt::value_type;
>     value_type temp = static_cast<value_type&&>(*a); // aka std::move
>     *a = static_cast<value_type&&>(*b);
>     *b = static_cast<value_type&&>(temp);
> }
>
> template<class T>
> void iter_swap<T*>(T * a, T * b)
> {
>     T temp = static_cast<T&&>(*a); // aka std::move
>     *a = static_cast<T&&>(*b);
>     *b = static_cast<T&&>(temp);
> }
>
> template<class InputIt>
> InputIt next(InputIt it, int distance)
> {
>     return it + distance;
> }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

I guess eventually, you would want it to be sorted by min value of a word.
a short word has less "value" than a long one and because letters weight less than words I would sort it by the total ascii value of each word.
In this case you don't need to use 2 sorts and merge, calc the ascii value of each object and sort by it.

Comment: So you say run on the ascii values, since a is less than b and less than three and so on?

Comment: @zavier Exactly !

Comment: While it seems really useful, the only reason I am hesitant is that I am afraid implementing it with my custom string class would be a nightmare, am I making it worse than it actually is?

Comment: I think you do, if you can iterate each char on your string (and obviously, you can) so the only thing left to do is calc the value by converting char to int.

Comment: Would you be willing to shove me in the right direction code wise? I know it may seem like I know what im doing but im pretty sure after every semester and with every new class I get dumber

Comment: As a student I dont think you can use something that not implemented by yourself like std:sort.
Conversion done much simple than you think, if you have char var called cChar, you can convert it to int by int(cChar) and you will get the numeric value of this char by ascii table, sum all chars of each object and done. :)

Comment: Thanks just did it, and it works not too hard at all quick question, small thing when i run the code I get a number one lower than the supposed value, any idea why that might be, and thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

If you must chain the two algorithms together, for a school assignment or whatever, you will need to implement stable partition (or use std::stable_partition).

EDIT - After reading your "NOTE", I should mention that another way to appease the teacher would be to implement a third version of quicksort that uses both criteria in the predicate. See `shorter_less` below. Better yet, pass the predicate as a function pointer into a single, unified quicksort, the way std::sort and std::stable_sort do it.  I.e. ...

Here's the C++ way of doing it all in one go ...

```
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

using std::string;

static bool shorter_less( const string& L, const string &R) {
    if (L.length() == R.length()) return L<R;
    else return L.length() < R.length();
}

int main() {
    using str_vec = std::vector<string>;
    str_vec vec{ "xxzy" , "Alphonse", "Betty", "pea", "nuts", "z" };
    std::sort(vec.begin(), vec.end(), shorter_less);
}
```